# Debug: Cisco VPN Router runs 100% CPU

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, routing, kernel

I've turned logging on and all I am currently getting are Debug/Kernel logs. Nothing above debug.

This was also during offsite hours when hardly any traffic was going on. I have also upgraded to the latest firmware and cisco confirmed that the firmware is glitch free.

What would be my next course of action to debug this?

model: RV180

Comment: Isn't this what Cisco support is for?

Comment: Can you provide, "show process cpu history", "show process", "show processes memory", "show logging", and "show running-config"?  We could much better troubleshoot the issue with (this/more) information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using an RV180. We've seen problems with that line of routers. Get an 861 or something running real IOS. The ISA500s turned out to be OK even though they've been discontinued - if you want a GUI.

That said, try to be more selective with what you are logging if possible. Pull back on the scope of the logging and you should see the cpu usage come down. Try setting to a warning level or information first.